# How to make a window open when clicking on a specific cell of the antd calendar?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, calendar, vite, antd

Good afternoon!
I use a calendar from **ant design** and I want to make it so that when you click on any of the calendar tiles with a date, a small modal window opens right above this tile, tell me how this can be implemented?
That is, the position of the window changes depending on which tile was clicked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBr3z.png)

I don't even know how to approach this task to be honest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a general popup for all the date selections simplest way is using `onSelect` event of the calendar.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Calendar } from 'antd';

const CalApp = () => {

  onSelect = (value) => {
    // Handle the click event on a calendar day
    alert(`Selected Date: ${value.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`);
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <Calendar
        onSelect={this.onSelect}
        ...
      />
    );
  }
}

export default CalApp ;
```

If you can add a button inside a date cell, you can use `cellRender` [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-si3u1u?file=demo.tsx)

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import type { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import { Button, CalendarProps, message, Popconfirm } from 'antd';
import { Calendar } from 'antd';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const confirm = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    console.log(e);
    message.success('Click on Yes');
  };

  const cancel = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    console.log(e);
    message.error('Click on No');
  };

  const dateCellRender = (value: Dayjs) => {
    return (
      <Popconfirm
        title="Delete the task"
        description={`Are you sure to delete this task${value}?`}
        onConfirm={confirm}
        onCancel={cancel}
        okText="Yes"
        cancelText="No"
      >
        <Button>pop up</Button>
      </Popconfirm>
    );
  };

  const cellRender: CalendarProps<Dayjs>['cellRender'] = (current, info) => {
    if (info.type === 'date') return dateCellRender(current);
    return info.originNode;
  };

  return <Calendar cellRender={cellRender} />;
};

export default App;
```